# URL not decode the message

Tags: php

I got the issue in integration of route mobile sms gateway. In URL i send the message but URL does not accept space so encode the message by using encode function, then URL accept the message but after using encode, SMS also receive as encoded.
please check the code.

```php
    $text = "" . $sms_message . "   " . $user_data['otp'] . "";
    $message = $this->myUrlEncode($text);
  
    $URL = "http://rslr.connectbind.com:8080/bulksms/bulksms?username=$username&password=$password&type=0&dlr=1&destination=$number&source=$source&message=$message";
  
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_PORT => "8080",
        CURLOPT_URL =>   $URL,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 30,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Accept: */*",
            "Connection: keep-alive",
            "Host: rslr.connectbind.com:8080",
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

So, what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Please share what `myUrlEncode` does. It is just guessing work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your encode function does, but if you just wrap ‘urlencode’ you can use ‘urldecode’.

```
$response = urldecode(curl_exec($curl));
```